# Can I merge Jenkinsfiles in a separate job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have separate Jenkinsfiles currently to do these things:

1. Create our infrastructure
2. Deploy configuration management to our infrastructure and do some stuff.
3. Deploy our application and do tests.

We like having these separate as it allows us to do regular testing of separates parts of the pipeline.

I can test if the infrastructure part is working. My colleague can test if the deploy + test application part is working. We currently have 3 Jenkinsfiles and 3 Jenkins jobs.

Would it be possible to have a 4th job that would merge all these Jenkinsfiles together? The combined amount of parameters for all 3 jobs is around 12 now.

Is there a feature in Jenkins 2 pipelines for this or would I need to create a 4th Jenkinsfile that asks for all these 12 parameters and use "job build:" to run the jobs consecutively?

This would only show 3 stages, instead of all stages. Is there a way to merge all 3 Jenkinsfiles automatically and have Jenkins fetch the parameters from those combined 3 Jenkinsfiles?